# Finding unused CRM fields

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2015

We are currently using CRM 2015 ONLINE and we have a requirement to find and delete unused fields from CRM organization. Also, we feel there are certain performance gains to be had by removing unused fields – especially Lookup and Picklist/Option Set-type fields. Since, these kinds of fields force CRM to get information from other database tables every time they are referenced, so it’s wasted effort to try to fetch that data when you know there never will be anything to fetch.

Do you have any way to figure out, which “columns” are null 
OR
Which columns has count 0 ? And does not contain any value in Table?
OR
I'm looking for a script/way (to do in crm ONLINE) that will do a count for every column in a table including the number of null values

[image: Expected results]

Answer (score 1):

You could write a console app that Performs a Metadata request to get all of the columns for each entity and create a custom Query Expression for each column for each entity.  It wouldn't be very performant, but it would work.  It would also take a few days to write as well.

Answer (score 0):

As for me the easiest way is following:

1. Request Organization DB backup from Microsoft.
2. Restore that backup somewhere.
3. Use t-sql script to analyze usage of attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment @Andrii. Much Appreciated! (I had a thought with this, but as of now it seems to be a very long & time consuming process, as lot of approvals & other stuff would be involved in this process down the hierarchy.) So, what I was wondering if we can do it custom, using CRM SDK.

Do you think if there is way using CRM SDK, we can achieve this? Any pointers would be helpful.

I also came across with a tool for this called, “CRM Data Detective”. But maybe it is not supported for CRM 2015. 
FYR: http://crmdatadetective.codeplex.com/

Wud be happy to listen your views!

Comment: Seems like CRM Data Detective should work fine. You just need to migrate it to 2015 properly or ask author of tool for a version that compatible with CRM 2015.

Answer (score 0):

When you need to find out which (custom) fields are used on forms and in views and which are not, you may find the Metadata Browser in the [XrmToolBox](http://www.xrmtoolbox.com/) useful. It is free and as open source available on [GitHub](https://github.com/MscrmTools/XrmToolBox).